# Designed a Buck converter, Need to add galvanic isolation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics

I have made calculations for a 22-12V 10W buck converter, which runs at 15 KHz, and uses a half-bridge configuration to deliver power through a 1.34mH inductor. 
[image]
after simulation in PSIM the interleaved converter seem to function properly looking at the different curves, this was at a fixed duty cycle without feedback control. 
I choose a MOSFET driver to be driven by a micro-controller, and got 2 MOSFETS with the proper ratings. However, I ordered the wrong [inductor](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/287-3658). This inductor has galvanic isolation, and has 2 inputs and 2 outputs. Is there any way I can salvage the inductor? I looked online but failed to see buck converters that have galvanic isolation. I understand the inductor in the link has actually 2 inductors. If I need a 1.34 mH inductor can I just use the first (primary) side as the inductor for this application and neglect the secondary?

Comment: the image in the picture appears improper because it has no values for any of the components. Please review yourself the question once.

Comment: You can use just one side. Or, given the two windings are equivalent, you can parallel them (going the same direction) and get the same inductance with half the resistance. But, that is a common mode choke, therefore the saturation current is not even specified and is likely to be much less than the 6A DC Current spec.

Comment: @Nadim, if you haven't considered pcb and component parasitics you will proabably need to

Comment: That inductor is unsuitable even if you paralleled the windings.

Comment: @rioraxe: according to this [link](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-15/series-and-parallel-inductors/) If I put two equivalent inductors in parallel I get total inductance of L/2, am I right? Regarding the common mode choke, can I use that for this application? The saturation current way over my current requirement (.6A maximum).

Comment: @Andyaka: Why is it unsuitable if I parallel the windings?

Comment: If you do some digging it is only specified for line frequencies up to 400 Hz and I made the giant leap to assume that operating at 15 kHz is going to pose it significant problems. Choice of an inductor for any switching regulator is something to be done carefully. The higher the power, the more care and attention to detail is needed. Bottom line (as always and for ever) is it MUST have a good data sheet and it must appear to tick all the boxes.

Comment: @Andyaka: I understand, it makes sense. If I want to try it before returning it, do you think it will work if I parallel the wingdings? if yes, what issues might I encounter?

Comment: @Nadim, just to confirm what user28910 had already said, since the two coils/windings are on the same core, they do not work like two separate inductors when put in parallel and that is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a reason why this inductor is not suitable: the core. This is a common-mode choke, designed for EMI suppression, not energy storage.  The 6 amp rating is for differential-mode current, that is, current flowing through one winding and returning through the other.  Since the currents are equal and in opposite directions, the resulting MMFs cancel and (neglecting leakage inductance) there is no net flux produced. So the current rating is more a function of resistive losses than core saturation.

Most common-mode chokes are wound on a high permeability ungapped ferrite core.  Using only one winding, the core will saturate at far less than the 6 amp rating, even less than your 0.6 amp maximum.

Even if you operate below saturation, the inductor will likely be noisy at 15kHz because high permeability ferrites have a magnetostriction behavior. Also, ferrites for EMI suppression have high losses at higher (200+ kHz) frequencies.  Switching at 15kHz, you have harmonics in this range, degrading efficiency.

By the way, because both windings are on the same core, connecting the windings in parallel (assuming the MMFs are in the same direction) is like using a heavier wire.  Compared to a single winding, the dc resistance will be half, but the inductance will be the same.